# Cannot override C-l bindings in helm-mode

Tags: helm, keymap

I'm trying to override the keymap `C-l` binding when in helm mode. 
However, it doesn't seem to be working - even though my other bindings work.

I've tried setting `C-l` to nil and also binding to both helm-map and helm-find-files-map but it still has the default binding.

```
    (define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "C-l") nil)
    (define-key helm-map (kbd "C-l") nil)

    (define-key helm-map (kbd "C-l") 'helm-execute-persistent-action)
    (define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "C-l") 'helm-execute-persistent-action)
```

Is there something that I'm missing here that is preventing me from overriding this keybinding?

Comment: You're definitely evaluating the lines? The first line (rebinding it to nil in `helm-find-files-map`) is enough to make `C-l` do nothing on my computer, testing it with `C-x  C-f`. There is a different keymap used for finding files in other window; that's `helm-read-file-map`.

Answer (score 3):

Turns [zck](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/97/zck) was correct here.
I wasn't using `helm-read-file-map` in my situation - which was to go down a level in helm mode.